# Adding items to an empty list with input after every item is listed

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create an empty list where the user can add grocery items to the list. Every time an item is added I want an input to ask if they're done. If they're done I want to items in the lists to print out. If they're not done I want them to be able to add one more item. I want this to repeat until the user no longer wants to add anymore item. I kind of know what method to use but having a hard time putting it together.

I think I will be using
while loop,
input,
if and else,
for loop.

```
list = []
grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()

while are_you_done == "no":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    list.append(grocery_item)
    for item in grocery_item:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid using 'list' as variable name... it's a reserved name for... just that, lists. Initialize your loop variable before and use that to query input only in the loop. And move the output of the final list to after the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
mlist = list()
# initialize the ending condition
are_you_done = "no"

# loop as long as the user answers 'no'
while are_you_done == "no":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    mlist.append(grocery_item)

# only print the whole list when you're done with adding stuff
for item in mlist:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason why used list() instead of [] ?

Comment: Not in particular. It simply shows that list is an unfortimate variable name

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are printing out each character of `grocery_item` instead of each entry of `list`.

```py
for item in grocery_item:
    print(item)
```

should be

```py
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

to print out each element in the grocery list.

However, you are also printing the list each time through the loop. From your question, it seems you meant to print it only once the user has finished adding items. To do that, move the printing loop to outside, after the while loop completes:

```py
while are_you_done == "no":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    list.append(grocery_item)
    for item in list:
        print(item)
```

to

```py
while are_you_done == "no":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    list.append(grocery_item)
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

The last problem, is that you are not saving the first item to the list. The code enters the loop without saving that first item:

```py
list = []
grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
# Not saving...

while are_you_done == "no":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    list.append(grocery_item)
    for item in grocery_item:
        print(item)
```

to

```py
list = []
grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
list.append(grocery_item)

while are_you_done == "no":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    list.append(grocery_item)
    for item in grocery_item:
        print(item)
```

That would fix your code, but I personally dislike running code outside and inside of the loop. It causes you to duplicate code and encounter this sort of problems. I'd suggest you try removing the first grocery list item completely, and just initialize `are_you_done` to `no`:

```py
list = []
are_you_done = "no"

while are_you_done == "no":
    grocery_item = input("Add to Grocery ")
    are_you_done = input("Are you done? ").lower()
    list.append(grocery_item)
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

Comment: this works great. I think my major issue was I had the are you done input outside of my loop.